Metaplex, CPI burn cNFT throwing Invalid root recomputed from proof
I have this instruction, calling Metaplex Bubblegum program, using CPI, for burning a cNFT.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use mpl_bubblegum::instructions::BurnCpiBuilder;

use crate::common::*;


#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct DCBurnArgs {
  pub root: [u8; 32],
  pub data_hash: [u8; 32],
  pub creator_hash: [u8; 32],
  pub leaf_index: u32,
  pub nonce: u64,

  pub leaf_id: Pubkey,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(args: DCBurnArgs)]
pub struct DCBurn<'info> {

  /// CHECK: Safe. Tree config.
  pub tree_config: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Merkle Tree
  #[account(mut)]
  pub merkle_tree: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(mut)]
  pub leaf_owner: Signer<'info>,
    
  /// CHECK. Safe.
  pub leaf_delegate: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  // #[account(mut)]
  // pub payer: Signer<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Bubblegum program.
  #[account(address = bubblegum_program_id::ID)]
  pub mpl_bubblegum_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Compression program.
  #[account(address = compression_program_id::ID)]
  pub spl_compression_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Log wrapper program.
  pub log_wrapper_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

}

impl DCBurn<'_> {

  pub fn handler<'info>(ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, DCBurn<'info>>, args: DCBurnArgs) -> Result<()> {

    let _ = BurnCpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.mpl_bubblegum_program)
    // Merkle Tree
    .tree_config(&ctx.accounts.tree_config)
    .merkle_tree(&ctx.accounts.merkle_tree)

    // NFT 
    .leaf_owner(&ctx.accounts.leaf_owner, true)
    .leaf_delegate(&ctx.accounts.leaf_delegate, false)

    // Merkle retrieval
    .root(args.root)
    .data_hash(args.data_hash)
    .creator_hash(args.creator_hash)
    .nonce(args.nonce)
    .index(args.leaf_index)

     // Program
    .log_wrapper(&ctx.accounts.log_wrapper_program)
    .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
    .compression_program(&ctx.accounts.spl_compression_program)
    
    // Remaining accounts
    .add_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts
      .iter()
      .map(|account| (account, false, false))
      .collect::<Vec<_>>()
      .as_slice())
    
    // invoke
    .invoke();

    Ok(())
  }
}

On the client side, I first run getAssetWithProof from Metaplex SDK, so I pass everything correctly.
await getAssetWithProof(this.umi, assetId)

I also get the canopyDepth
let treeAccount = await ConcurrentMerkleTreeAccount.fromAccountAddress(provider.connection, new PublicKey(merkleTree.publicKey))
  const canopyDepth = treeAccount.getCanopyDepth()

And here is my ts code for calling my program's method called dcBurnSimple:
const txSig = await program.methods.dcBurnSimple({
    leafIndex: meta.leafIndex,
    leafId: meta.leafId,
    root: meta.root,
    dataHash: meta.dataHash,
    creatorHash: meta.creatorHash,
    nonce: meta.nonce
  })
  .accounts({
    treeConfig: accounts.treeConfig,
    merkleTree: accounts.merkleTree,
    
    leafOwner: accounts.leafOwner.publicKey,
    leafDelegate: accounts.leafDelegate.publicKey,
    
    mplBubblegumProgram: MPL_BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID,
    splCompressionProgram: SPL_ACCOUNT_COMPRESSION_ADDRESS,
    logWrapperProgram: SPL_NOOP_PROGRAM_ID,
    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
  })
  .remainingAccounts(proof.slice(0, assetWithProof.proof.length - (!!canopyDepth ? canopyDepth : 0)))
  .signers([
    accounts.leafOwner
  ])
  .rpc({skipPreflight: false})

The thing is it's not working throwing Invalid root recomputed from proof using either my program and CPI call to Bubblegum or the Metaplex SDK burn method.
Error stack trace:
        logs: [
    'Program GHftzfU2Up9BUnobv6js3QzzkqeeTZTnfT6oqDrhaZKg invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: DcBurnSimple',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Burn',
    'Program cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK invoke [3]',
    'Program log: Instruction: ReplaceLeaf',
    'Program log: Attempting to fill in proof',
    'Program consumption: 108203 units remaining',
    'Program log: Active Index: 7',
    'Program log: Rightmost Index: 6',
    'Program log: Buffer Size: 8',
    'Program log: Leaf Index: 5',
    'Program log: Fast-forwarding proof, starting index 7',
    'Program consumption: 105310 units remaining',
    'Program consumption: 105206 units remaining',
    'Program log: Error using concurrent merkle tree: Invalid root recomputed from proof',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in programs/account-compression/src/lib.rs:273. Error Code: ConcurrentMerkleTreeError. Error Number: 6001. Error Message: Concurrent merkle tree error.',
    'Program cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK consumed 47788 of 145182 compute units',
    'Program cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK failed: custom program error: 0x1771',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY consumed 82534 of 179928 compute units',
    'Program BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY failed: custom program error: 0x1771',
    'Program GHftzfU2Up9BUnobv6js3QzzkqeeTZTnfT6oqDrhaZKg consumed 102606 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program GHftzfU2Up9BUnobv6js3QzzkqeeTZTnfT6oqDrhaZKg failed: custom program error: 0x1771'
  ],
  error: {
    errorCode: { code: 'ConcurrentMerkleTreeError', number: 6001 },
    errorMessage: 'Concurrent merkle tree error',
    comparedValues: undefined,
    origin: { file: 'programs/account-compression/src/lib.rs', line: 273 }
  },
  _programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack {
    stack: [
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(GHftzfU2Up9BUnobv6js3QzzkqeeTZTnfT6oqDrhaZKg)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(BGUMAp9Gq7iTEuizy4pqaxsTyUCBK68MDfK752saRPUY)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(cmtDvXumGCrqC1Age74AVPhSRVXJMd8PJS91L8KbNCK)]]
    ]
  }

Any feedback is very much appreciated! 

The issue was that I wasn't passing the right leafDelegate. You can check you're passing the right leafDelegate by comparing it with what you get from Metaplex getAssetWithProof method.
